# Pure-CSS checkbox with label not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a check to be displayed when the associated checkbox input is checked. Currently, this isn't working unless I move the input field outside of the *span* tag.

***The HTML structure can't be altered because of the use of *.NET* (At least this is my understanding)***

```css
body {
  background-color: #1790b5;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.checkBox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.checkBoxLabel {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.checkBoxLabel span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  transform-origin: center;
  border: 2px solid #bdc3c7;
  vertical-align: -6px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.checkBoxLabel span:before, .checkBoxLabel span:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}

.inputCheckBox {
  display: none;
}
.inputCheckBox:checked + label span {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.inputCheckBox:checked + label span:after {
  content: "\2714";
  color: blue;
  top: -6px;
  font-size: 28px;
  left: 2px;
}
```

```html
   <!-- .Net Code -->
  <div class="checkBox">
    <asp:CheckBox name="cb1" class="box" ID="cb1" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
    <asp:Label AssociatedControlId="cb1" class="checkBox-label" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </div>

  <!-- renders: -->

  <div class="checkBox">
    <span class="box">
      <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb1">
    </span>
    <label for="cb1" class="checkBox-label">Check</label>
  </div>
```

I haven't tried to do this with a JS click event function but I thought it would be "simpler" if I did this with *JUST* CSS.

Comment: Any chance you can provide the rendered CSS instead of LESS/SASS?

Comment: Depending on your needs, you can ditch the asp.net server controls and use generic HTML controls. `<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" class="box" ID="cb1" runat="server" ><label for="cb1" class="checkBox-label" runat="server"></label>`. By adding `runat="server"` you have exposed the generic controls to be able to be accessed server side with their Ids, much like WebForm controls.

Comment: Mmm. I need the check box's status to be passed server side.

Comment: Do you mean its checked status? If so you should have access to it. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputcheckbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JonP Yes I meant the checked status.

Comment: Sounds like you should be able to use the generic controls then. Just make sure to add `runat="server"` and you should be fine. You can then set and check the checked status with `cb1.Checked` in your code behind. I'm going to flesh this out into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments we've traded, this is less a CSS issue and more a Webforms issue.

Addressing the CSS issues first, given the way the HTML is rendered by the webforms control you can't do what you need with CSS as effectively you're after something similar to a parent selector, which does not exist.

Now to fix your problem.

The inbuilt webforms controls can be great, but as you've discovered, sometimes they come with unwanted markup and overhead. Sometimes you want more control over the HTML that is rendered. This is where adding `runat="server"` to regular HTML elements can be of great assistance. You get most of the webform serverside support with more control over the final HTML output.

In your instance you'd want something like:

```
<div class="checkBox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" class="box" ID="cb1" runat="server" >
  <label id="cb1Label" for="cb1" class="checkBox-label" runat="server"></label>
</div>
```

**EDIT CSS Change**

As we've subtly changed the HTML, we need to change your SCSS. Removing the nesting with `.box`

```
@mixin checkBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

body {
  background: #2c3e50;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
}

.checkBox-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 2em;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    @include checkBox;
    content: "";
    border: 2px solid #bdc3c7;
    background: #fff;
  }
  &:after {
    @include checkBox;
  }
}


/* Checkbox */

// when input checked. Add checkbox to lable after class
.checkBox>input[type="checkbox"]+.checkBox-label::after {
  content: "\2714";
  color: #000;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

// Onclick adds / removes check from checkboxes
.checkBox input[type="checkbox"] + .checkBox-label::after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.checkBox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkBox-label::after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpRMdb ... you'll note there is still some formatting to do.

**END Edit**

Now server-side you can access these much like you would a regular webform control:

```
//TO Set
cb1.Checked = True;
cb1Label.InnerText = "Some Label";
cb1Label.Attributes["for"] = cb1.ClientId;

//To Get
bool isChecked = cb1.Checked;
```

For more information see: [HtmlInputCheckbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputcheckbox(v=vs.110).aspx)  and for the complete set: [HtmlControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Jon. I wasn't sure if adding the "runat='server'" would work if I just slapped it onto my HTML elements.I'll try this out at report back the results

Comment: Sad to report that I was not able to get this functional. I'm trying to display the check inside the checkbox with the help of a JS click event

Comment: Not giving up on this....It looks like we need to tweak the CSS, which I've now done.

Comment: From the edits, you made to your answer I was able to get the checkbox to produce the behavior I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way.
pick the neighbor of checkbox as a span and let the span as a parent div of label.
for label you can use psuedo class **::before** and **::after** for css background and content.

```css
.checkbox {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
       padding-left: 20px;
}

.checkbox label {
    min-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.checkbox span label::before {
    -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(120,130,140,.13);
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 17px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    width: 17px;
    outline: 0!important;
}
.checkbox-primary input[type=checkbox]:checked+span label::before {
    background-color: #ab8ce4;
    border-color: #ab8ce4;
}
.checkbox label::after {
    color: #2b2b2b;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: -19px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 16px;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked+span label::after {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
.checkbox-primary input[type=checkbox]:checked+span label::after {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                                        <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
                                       <span>
                                       <label for="checkbox2"> Primary </label>
                                       </span>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
@mixin checkBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

body {
  background: #2c3e50;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 6px;
  top: 1px;
}

.checkBox-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 2em;
  width: auto;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    @include checkBox;
    content: "";
    border: 2px solid #bdc3c7;
    background: #fff;
  }
  &:after {
    @include checkBox;
  }
}


/* Checkbox */

// when input checked. Add checkbox to lable after class
.box>input[type="checkbox"]+.checkBox-label::after {
  content: "\2714";
  color: #000;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

// Onclick adds / removes check from checkboxes
.box input[type="checkbox"]+.checkBox .checkBox-label::after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.box input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkBox .checkBox-label::after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
 
//.Net Code
  <div class="checkBox">
<asp:CheckBox name="cb1" class="box" ID="cb1" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
<asp:Label AssociatedControlId="cb1" class="checkBox-label" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
 //renders:
<div class="checkBox">
  <span class="box">
    <label class="checkBox-label"><input type="checkbox" name="cb">Check</label>
  </span>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what you have done to solve the problem instead of just posting code. Particularly when the snippet does not work (due to LESS instead of native CSS). Furthermore you've changed the HTML structure which you can't do by the terms of the question, due to the way the give asp.net controls work.